# Chrome/Firebox max width 1519px on a 1920px wide screen

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, resolution

I have a Lenovo E560 with a 1920 x 1080 pixel screen.

Chrome is open and at 100% zoom, but the view port when stretched to full width is 1519px wide.

Why is this so?

Comment: Is the webpage zoomed at all? You can press `control` +`0` to reset the page zoom. Otherwise Windows might be scaling your display. You can check the display scaling by going to Start > Settings > System > Display  http://www.pcworld.com/article/2953978/displays/use-windows-10s-individual-display-scaling-to-perfect-your-multi-monitor-setup.html

Comment: Hi @Mokubai, I confirmed that the zoom was at 100%, and the issue remained.